# Borgbackup - Functionality & Questions

Tags: ubuntu, bash, backup, rsync

I want to move away from rsync and so to Borgbackup and store them in an off-site backup repo.

Now: If I restore e.g. a follow backup are then also all files of the previous backups present + the incremental if I want to restore everything or are only the new/changed files in the folder (mount)?

- Are file permissions also backed up?
- Are UNIX group:owner also backed up?
- Can I also sync the repos via rsync to the PC from off-site storage?
- Is there anything else to consider?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sure, but I also want user experience and suggestions 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now: If I restore e.g. a follow backup are then also all files of the previous backups present + the incremental

Yes, see https://borgbackup.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html#main-features

But to repeat the most important thing from that page:

Borg is not incremental – it is *deduplicating,* much like Git. This means that each backup results in a snapshot containing *all* files that were specified to be backed up, whether they were "new/changed" or not.

(Of course, the backup process skips copying files if their content is already present in the repository, so the backup speed is the same of an incremental backup.)

> Are file permissions also backed up?

Yes, see https://borgbackup.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage/general.html#support-for-file-metadata

> Are UNIX group:owner also backed up?

Yes, see https://borgbackup.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage/general.html#support-for-file-metadata

> Can I also sync the repos via rsync to the PC from off-site storage?

Yes, see https://borgbackup.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#can-i-copy-or-synchronize-my-repo-to-another-location

However, you can already use `borg extract` or `borg mount` against external storage, without needing to copy the repository into your PC. This even works for remote SSH servers, as long as they also have borg installed.

> Is there anything else to consider?

Yes, see https://borgbackup.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html